# My xml is changing all the nodes with a text value set as "" to having no value for text, how can I stop this?

Tags: xml, vba

When I attempt to change the value of a node in my xml file, every xml node that I set to have a text value that was nothing ie text = "" automatically gets set to having no text value at all instead of just a text value that is null. I was wondering if there was a way to stop this.

To show what I mean:

```
    <Classes>
      <_1_08_2020>
        <Morning>
          <Client1>
            <Payed></Payed>
```

the payed element has a text property that is empty  but after i re-save the xml file it automatically becomes this:

```
        <Classes>
          <_1_08_2020>
            <Morning>
              <Client1>
                <Payed>
                </Payed>
```

which has no text value. The problem arrises when i attempt to use this code

```
Dim Classes As New XmlDocument
    Classes.Load("Classes.xml")

    Dim attrClient1Payed As XmlNode
    attrClient1 = Classes.SelectSingleNode("/Classes/" & strDate & "/" & strMorningAfternoon & "/Client1/Payed")
    If attrClient1Payed.InnerText = ""
       'do the thing i want
    End if
```

it throws an exception saying that attrClient1Payed was nothing on the third last line.

Comment: How are you saving the file? Also, are you sure it matters? Both xml are equivalent. It depends what you are doing with the xml afterwards.

Comment: It's crucial when asking a question here that you also include the relevant lines of code that cause the issue. As @Bryn pointed out: from the perspective of XML, the two files are identical, as XML ignores line breaks (CrLf). It's just that the program I use to view the XML interprets the line break and displays the XML that way.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your variable as

```
 Dim attrClient1Payed As XmlNode
```

Then use a different variable name:

```
    attrClient1 = Classes.SelectSingleNode("/Classes/" & strDate & "/" & strMorningAfternoon & "/Client1/Payed")
```

You need to do this:

```
    attrClient1Payed = Classes.SelectSingleNode("/Classes/" & strDate & "/" & strMorningAfternoon & "/Client1/Payed")
```

Comment: thank you, i switched it up but i'm still getting the same error message

Comment: if attrClient1Payed is null then something is wrong with your XPath expression. Can you edit your post to show how strDate and strMorningAfter are defined. You could also output the value of "/Classes/" & strDate & "/" & strMorningAfternoon & "/Client1/Payed", so you can check that it is what you expect it to be.